# Laravel 6 - How to Log All URL's of User Visited

Tags: laravel, logging, laravel-6

I want to log all URL's that user visited. But there's not the url i want to logged from my code. Here are the code that im done, please give me some advise. Thanks and appreciate.

**Web Routes**

```
Route::get('/{url}', 'LogController@myTestAddToLog')->where('url', '[\w\d\-]+(.*)');
```

**Log Controller**

```
public function myTestAddToLog()
{
    \LogActivity::addToLog('My Testing Add To Log.');
}
```

**App/Helpers LogActivity**

```
public static function addToLog($subject)
{
    $log = [];
    $log['url'] = Request::fullUrl();
    $log['ip'] = Request::ip();
    $log['user_id'] = auth()->check() ? auth()->user()->id : 1;
    LogActivityModel::create($log);
}
```

Comment: Create a middle ware and use in `kernel.php` file

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to create a middleware.

```
php artisan make:middleware AddToLog
```

And then, put your code inside the middleware.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use App\LogActivityModel;

class AddToLog
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        if(auth()->user()) {
            LogActivityModel::create([
                'url' => request()->fullUrl(),
                'ip' => request()->ip(),
                'user_id' => auth()->id(),
            ]);
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Then, inside `app/Http/kernel.php`, add your middleware to `$middleware`. This would allow any URL called would trigger this code.

```
protected $middleware = [
    ...
    \App\Http\Middleware\AddToLog::class,
];
```

Comment: hi @Adlan, i can't get my user_id. It's NULL.

Comment: Can you verify you are indeed calling the URL while logged in? You can try to log ```auth()->user()``` and see what you get.

Comment: I'm getting NULL

Comment: @user9912010 That means your are not logged in. Please check again. Btw, I already put if-else condition to log ONLY when user is logged in, so you won't get null result in your DB.

Comment: Yup, but i'm sure logged in and i'm using dd('Auth::user()->id') for testing. Btw, i solved it! $next($request) must declare before create data. Thanks for your solution!

Answer (score 2):

For those who still has the issue I had modified a bit the answer provided by @Adlan and based on the comments of his answer. Since you will be logging the activities after the request has been performed, the accepted answer needs to be modified. Following is the modified code.

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    $response = $next($request);

    if(auth()->user()) {
        Activity::create([
            'url' => request()->fullUrl(),
            'ip_address' => request()->ip(),
            'user_id' => auth()->id(),
        ]);

    }

    return $response;

}
```

First, the response for the next request is saved. Then user authentication is checked and finally, the response is returned.

Reference : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59816949/7070809

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below code to log all url that user has visited

```
Log::info(url()->full()); // For just loggin
```

And for storing user log create table store the **url** with **timestamp** and **IP**